# In react, I want my react state to be empty if there is no error coming from backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I store the back-end error response in a state with the help of axios library, and I apply the validation using serverError('') state, like if the state values is empty then it means there is no error is coming from backend so I apply a condtion inside useEffect() function, if(serverError.length === 0) then it should render the Home component with the help of useNavigate() function, and it is not working.

```
const loginUser = async () => {

        await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login/', loginInfo).then((res) => {

            sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', `Bearer ${res.data.myAccessToken}`);
            sessionStorage.setItem('refreshToken', `Bearer ${res.data.myRefreshToken}`);

        }).catch((err) => {
            setServerError(err.response.data.res);

        })

};
```

I already tried doing this:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
     if(serverError.length === 0){
      navigate('/') // navigate to Home page
      }
    },[])
```

However it didn't work because as we already know useeffect renders every time our component renders, so it empty the state and navigates to Home page even if there is error
coming from back-end.

My code:

```js
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [loginFormError, setLoginFormError] = useState({});
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);
  const [serverError, setServerError] = useState("");

  const [loginInfo, setLoginInfo] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const formSubmitHandle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  const inputChangeHandle = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setLoginInfo({
      ...loginInfo,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const loginClickHandle = async () => {
    setLoginFormError(loginValidate(loginInfo));
    setIsSubmit(true);

    await loginUser();
  };

  const loginValidate = (values) => {
    const err = {};
    const regEx = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/;

    // Username Validation :

    if (!values.email) {
      err.email = "*Email is empty";
    } else if (!regEx.test(values.email)) {
      err.email = "*Invalid email entered";
    }

    // Password validation :

    if (!values.password) {
      err.password = "*Password is empty";
    } else if (values.password.length < 6) {
      err.password = "*Password length can not be less than 6 char";
    }

    return err;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(loginFormError).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
      setServerError("");
    }
  }, [loginFormError]);

  const loginUser = async () => {
    try {
      await axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/login/", loginInfo)
        .then((res) => {
          sessionStorage.setItem(
            "accessToken",
            `Bearer ${res.data.myAccessToken}`,
          );
          sessionStorage.setItem(
            "refreshToken",
            `Bearer ${res.data.myRefreshToken}`,
          );
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setServerError(err.response.data.res);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to _do_ here, though? Are you trying to get the user sent to the homepage if their login doesn't work? Because if so, just... do that.  Await that loginUser but have it _return_the result of the login attempt, so you can call `navigate` if the login failed.

Comment: Your effect doesn't depend on anything: it runs once on initial render.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am validating the user here, if the user is not registered then I set the error with the help of setServerError('') and display it using serverError. I want to display Home Component if the serverError('') state is empty.

Comment: Step one: don't `catch` the axiom await, because there's nothing to catch. That axiom call only throws if there's a network error, so as long as your URL request is a _valid request_, axiom will return a normal response object. That `catch` will never kick in.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  yeh , Now I catch the success status code which I am sending from backend. I implemented if(res.status === 200) then it will only show the Home component, else it'll not.